# Plotting XTS Object using Quantmod

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I have an `xts` object with columns named Open, High, Low, Close among other calculated columns. Is it possible to use `quantmod` graphs to plot this columns in a candlestick graph? Any transformations required?

```
names(BTOW3XTS)
[1] "Ticker" "Open"   "High"   "Low"    "Avg"    "Close"  "Neg"    "Volume" "Var"    "Oscil"  "Vol60d" "PctVol"
```

Comment: Yes, you can make candlestick charts using quantmod.  See the tutorial here https://www.quantmod.com/examples/charting/

Comment: In addition to the tutorial pointed to by @lebelinoz, there is a newer version of the key function called `chart_Series()` (with an underscore) having slightly different functionality in the `quantmod` package.  There are also `ggplot2` variants such as the one provided in the [tidyquant](https://github.com/business-science/tidyquant) package.